# How can I configure an EhCache cache to use an LRU eviction strategy in version 3.8 of ehcache?

Tags: ehcache, lru

In version 3.8, how can I configure an `EhCache` cache to use an **LRU** eviction strategy?
I've looked at the `EvictionAdvisor`, but it only seems to get called for the most recently inserted item. So I can in essence say "yes" or "no" on evicting the most recently added item. But it is not useful in identifying other items that should be evicted.

I seem to recall that in EhCache 2.8 (it's been awhile), I could provide information in the `ehcache.xml` configuration file to specify that the cache use an **LRU** eviction strategy.

Answer (score 1):

int these two documentation mentioned that ehcache is using LRU as default eviction strategy :

> A cache eviction algorithm is a way of deciding which element to evict when the cache is full. In Ehcache, the MemoryStore may be limited in size (see How to Size Caches for more information). When the store gets full, elements are evicted. The eviction algorithms in Ehcache determine which elements are evicted. The default is LRU.

https://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/apis/cache-eviction-algorithms.html

> Ehcache uses Last Recently Used (LRU) as the default eviction strategy for the memory stores. The eviction strategy determines which cache entry is to be evicted when the cache is full.

https://springframework.guru/using-ehcache-3-in-spring-boot/

Comment: Thank you for your response @hdha. The information you have provided is for version 2.8 of ehcache. I am looking for information for version 3.8 of ehchache. I have updated my question to identify the ehcache version number.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged EhCache 3.10.
It seems that it always removes LRU mapping when it is full (heap limit is reached).

It is performed by `enforceCapacity` method in `org.ehcache.impl.internal.store.heap.OnHeapStore` class.

Mappings are compared by the following Comparator (inner class in `OnHeapStore`):

```java
  /**
   * Comparator for eviction candidates:
   * The highest priority is the ValueHolder having the smallest lastAccessTime.
   */
  private static final Comparator<ValueHolder<?>> EVICTION_PRIORITIZER = (t, u) -> {
    if (t instanceof Fault) {
      return -1;
    } else if (u instanceof Fault) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return Long.signum(u.lastAccessTime() - t.lastAccessTime());
    }
  };
```